# Why can't VS get the published PDBs for my NuGet packages?

Tags: .net, nuget, pdb-files, symbol-server

I used the [instructions](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/symbol-packages) at NuGet.org to create symbols packages for each of my open-source DLLs. For example, I used `nuget pack -Version 2.4.3 -symbols Core\Loyc.Essentials.nuspec` to create `Loyc.Essentials.2.4.3.nupkg` and `Loyc.Essentials.2.4.3.symbols.nupkg`.

Renaming the .nupkg to .zip, I verified that the `.symbols.nupkg` package contains the expected .dll, .pdb and .xml files in `lib\net45` and elsewhere, along with complete source code in a `src` folder.

I used AppVeyor to build my packages with a similar `nuget` command, and to [publish](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/nuget/) the symbol and non-symbol packages with these options:

`deploy:
    - provider: NuGet
      server:
      api_key:
          secure: DHTp3wMjKqyca2PWftol2wq7DxE9KdL8AizHVIS14T4DSSMXgc0bIiCGvvA8SkTH
      skip_symbols: false         # Whether to not publish symbol pkgs (src/pdb)
      artifact: /.*\.nupkg/
      on:
          branch: master          # Release from master branch only.
          appveyor_repo_tag: true # Deploy on tag push only.`

It seemed to work:

```
Publishing Loyc.Essentials.24.3.0.nupkg to https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package...OK
Publishing Loyc.Essentials.24.3.0.symbols.nupkg to https://nuget.smbsrc.net/api/v2/package...OK
```

I created a test project, added my packages via the VS NuGet GUI.

Finally, I followed the [detailed instructions here](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Home/VisualStudio) about how to use a symbol server. As [recommended at nuget.org](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/symbol-packages), I also added https://nuget.smbsrc.net to the list of "Symbol file (.pdb) locations" in VS options for Debugging | Symbols.

It doesn't work. I notice that in the SymbolCache there is a `FailedLoads` folder which contains a text file for each of my DLLs (and NUnit). The text file contains simply "PDB Not Found". Why might the PDB not have been found?

Comment: You can also use: https://chocolatey.org/packages/nugetpackageexplorer to explorer your package contents.

Comment: I just published symbols to nuget.smbsrc.net via appveyor, but when trying to list it it cannot be found (command nuget.exe list CoreDdd -source [http://nuget.smbsrc.net](http://nuget.smbsrc.net)); when listing Castle.Windsor (nuget.exe list Castle.Windsor -source [http://nuget.smbsrc.net](http://nuget.smbsrc.net) -allversions) it does not list latest versions; so something's rotten with nuget.smbsrc.net

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Seems like there isn't a lot of noise about this issue in general? Took me a while to track down people reproducing this issue.

Comment: If you are after the ability to debug your nuget package dll with the source code hosted on GitHub or BitBucket (with tools - options - debugging - "enable just my code" disabled), try this: https://github.com/ctaggart/SourceLink